# Visualizing All Possible Linear Regression Predictions from all Combinations of Regression Variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

So I have a set of 8 variables that I'm regressing against a dependent variable. Obviously I want to avoid over fitting so I want to see what all combinations of my 8 variables look like from a visual perspective to see if their is a correlation around the true model. Is there an R function or package that can help me do this? So far I've been using the "MuMin" package and the dredge() function to run all combinations of variables. What I'd like to do now is visualize all of them too. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: You realize that there are 2^8 = 256 subsets of your variables?

Comment: Yes, I do realize that. I want to see all possible linear regression predictions plotted out so I can see which models tend to give the same answer. Is there a way to save all the models to a list and then plot their predictions on the same graph?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called a Pairs Plot. Here is how you can implement it:

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)

ggpairs(data = your_data,
        columns = c('column name 1', 'column name 2', 'column name 3'),
        title = 'Pairs Plot')
```

The `columns` option within the `ggpairs` function allows you to only choose specific columns. If you want to automatically use every column in the pairs plot, omit the `columns` option:

```
ggpairs(data=your_data, title='Pairs Plot')
```

This is an example of a Pairs Plot:

[image: Pairs Plot]

Comment: I'm afraid that is not what I'm trying to achieve. I have a set of 8 variables in a linear regression model. I already have a dataset of all possible combinations of these variables in a linear regression format. Now I have a test dataset that I want to predict the outcome of the dependent variable using all 256 combinations of my 8 variables. Ideally I'd like one graph that shows all prediction results from my 256 linear models. The point of this is to visualize what the true outcome might be as the assumption is that the models will tend to group around the true prediction.

Comment: Try using `predict.lm` with your combination database as an input and evaluating it against your model. That will allow you to get predicted values for each combination. You can then add those predicted values as a column to your combination database. Once that column is added, use `ggplot2` to plot those results in whatever way you feel best displays the information.